# Why the last then() isn't executed?

Tags: mocha.js, es6-promise

I have the following code in my testUtils.js:

```
var truncateTable = function (model, trx) {
    console.log(`Truncating ${model.prototype.tableName}`);
    return knex(model.prototype.tableName).transacting(trx).truncate();
};

utils = {
    /**
     * Database utility for cleaning up its tables
     */
    teardown: function () {
        return knex.transaction(function (trx) {
            return knex.raw('SET foreign_key_checks = 0;').transacting(trx)
                .then(() => {                    
                    return truncateTable(models.ProductAnomaly,trx)
                })
                .then(() => {
                    return truncateTable(models.Product, trx);
                })
                .then(() => {
                    return truncateTable(models.TaskListItem, trx);
                })
                .then(() => {
                    return truncateTable(models.TaskList, trx);
                })
                .then(() => {
                    return truncateTable(models.User, trx);
                })
                .then(() => {
                    console.log('TRUNCATE FINISHED');
                    return knex.raw('SET foreign_key_checks = 1;').transacting(trx);
                });
        });
    }
}
```

When I run my test it prints:

```
Truncating products_anomalies
Truncating products
Truncating tasklist_items
Truncating tasklists
Truncating users
```

But as you may see the line `"TRUNCATE FINISHED"` is never printed, even though the action (truncate) is performed for all 5 tables. Why?

Here's the `before` method in my test file:

```
   before((done) => {
        this.timeout(10000);

        testUtils.teardown()
            .then(() => {
                return testUtils.setup();
            })
            .then(() => {
                done();
            })
            .catch(err => console.log(JSON.stringify(err)));
    })
```

Answer (score 0):

Most likely because you don't have a .catch in your teardown function, so if there was an error with your last truncateTable call, you would never know without a catch rejecting the promise.

Try:

```
.then(() => {
   return truncateTable(models.User, trx);
 })
 .then(() => {
   console.log('TRUNCATE FINISHED');
   return knex.raw('SET foreign_key_checks = 1;').transacting(trx);
 })
 .catch((err) => {
   throw err;
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

I found what was stopping the execution, the sequence of truncates and inclusion of sample data was taking more than 2000ms, then I had to increase the timeout value.